# How do I sum a customer name list of transactions into separate groups for each consultant on Google Sheet?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula

I have 3 sheets I work with.

Transaction Sheet - 
This file contains a long list of customer's names and individual transaction amounts each line.

Customer List Sheet - 
This file is a list of customers that has been grouped to each consultant's.

Summary Sheet - 
This file sums each Consultant's group of customers' transactions to their group.

I'm not exactly sure how to put together a formula that could skim through the Customer List and automatically sum up the individual transaction amounts to the Consultant's group.

"If "Name" = "Name from File", then send amount to group.

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VRt29wJkkTSdBFO1sitGdd70z7ALZZLQQ1nOpvdOVDw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Hi, hope this is a proper example.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VRt29wJkkTSdBFO1sitGdd70z7ALZZLQQ1nOpvdOVDw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **B3** and drag to the right:

```
=SUM(FILTER(Transactions!$B:$B, REGEXMATCH(Transactions!$A:$A, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDIRECT("Customer List!"&ADDRESS(2, 
 MATCH(B2, 'Customer List'!1:1, 0), 4)&":"&
 CHAR(64+MATCH(B2, 'Customer List'!1:1, 0)))))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Does the formula work if the original data is located in other Google Sheets for the transactions & name list?

Comment: you mean on different spreadsheet? yes, if you use IMPORTRANGE

Comment: you're a god-sent genius.